# Trigger an event on changing value in an input using JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, html

I want to trigger a function that changes the state of my button in a webpage. My input initially looks like this:-
[image]
Now when I type something in the text box, I want it to change like this:-
[image]
Notice the call button getting activated. I am using the onblur method to listen for changes, but this does not happen dynamically. I enter something in the box, and then click outside. That is the point when `onblur` executes.
**How do I call the onblur method as soon as the user changes the value in box?**
Here is the javascript code I am using

```
function toggleCallButton() {
    if (document.getElementById('dialArea').value == '') {
        document.getElementById('callButton').classList
                .add('input-group-addon-disabled');
        document.getElementById('callButton').classList
                .remove('input-group-addon-active');
    } else {
        document.getElementById('callButton').classList
                .remove('input-group-addon-disabled');
        document.getElementById('callButton').classList
                .add('input-group-addon-active');
    }
}
```

Comment: Just like the `onblur` event, there are also `onkeyup` and `onkeypress` events which you can utilize in your case

Comment: using onkeyup does the trick, but this causes my function to be called each time the user presses a key, a lot of unnecessary function calls. Was wondering if there was an elegant solution...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
<input type="text" onchange="toggleCallButton();"/>
```

Edit:

```
<body>
    <div>
        <input id="dialArea" type="text" onkeyup="toggleCallButton();" />
        <div id="callButton">Call Button</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
.input-group-addon-disabled{
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.input-group-addon-active{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function toggleCallButton() {
    if (document.getElementById('dialArea').value == '') {
        document.getElementById('callButton').classList.add('input-group-    addon-disabled');
        document.getElementById('callButton').classList.remove('input-group-addon-active');
    } else {
        document.getElementById('callButton').classList.remove('input-group-addon-disabled');
        document.getElementById('callButton').classList.add('input-group-addon-active');
    }
}
window.onload = toggleCallButton;
```

Comment: 'onchange' will work only if the value of textbox changed as compared to the value it has before. so for the first time it wont work because the state didn't change...does not work for me...

Comment: you should load the input with disabled style-classes at first. it's not the value change semantic of onchange that creates the problem, the problem is, onchange triggers when you loose focus from the input. if you ask me, you should check the input text at window.onload, add disabled-class if empty, and control the flow with onkeyup/onkeydown events. onkeyup="toggleCallButton();" should work

Comment: onkeyup="toggleCallButton();" will work, i agree but the function will be called each time I press a key...what if the function is big? it will be executed every time...

Comment: hmm. now, this changes everything :) why is your function big? you're just interested if there is a value or not, actually.